# JsonIgnore attribute keeps serializing properties in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-3.0

I've recently updated my API project to ASP.NET Core 3. Since then, `[JsonIgnore]` attributes are not working:

```
public class Diagnostico
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int TipoDiagnostico { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Orden { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime? FechaInicio { get; set; }

    public string TipoCodificacion { get; set; }

    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

All the properties of classes are being serialized. The API endpoints are in .NET Core 3, but all the logic is in .NET Standard 2.1. I have realized that the serializer has changed from `Newtonsoft.Json` to 
`System.Text.Json`. This package is not available in .NET Standard 2.1 (it only works in .NET Core) so to use `[JsonIgnore]` in Models inside .NET Standard projects I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[JsonIgnore]` is an JSON.NET attribute and won't be used by the new `System.Text.Json` serializer.

Since your application is an ASP.NET Core 3.0 `System.Text.Json` will be used by default. If you want to continue to consume the JSON.NET annotations, you have to use JSON.NET in ASP.NET Core 3

It's as easy as adding `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` to your MVC or WebApi Builder

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

or

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

for WebAPI-esque applications.

Comment: Well even though you might have AddNewtonsoftJson() as a method, it is useless if you don't explicitly add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson nuget to your project. Lost an hour finding that out!

Comment: System.Text.Json has its own built in JsonIgnoreAttribute as well, the same class name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1

also available in nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json

Answer (score 3):

For your .Net Standard project, grab `System.Text.Json` package from nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json

so you can use

```
System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreAttribute
```

instead of

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the Newtonsoft.json Nuget package if not already installed (this isn't included in .NET Core, so you'll need the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) nuget package)

In `program.cs`, add NewtonsoftJson as a service:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

or

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

In the entity class add

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Mark the navigation property in the entity class with:

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

e.g.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public MyProperty? MyProperty { get; set; }
```