# JSchemaGenerator -> Suppress property from generation in schema

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I want to generate a schema from an object. There are some properties which should not be serialized. The suppression works fine. When I generate the schema these properties occures there what is wrong for my case. But I couldn't find anything how I can suppress those properties from generating in the schema. How can I do this?

```cs
    public class Foo {

        public object[] Bar { get; set; }

        ...

        public bool ShouldSerializeBar()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    ...

    using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation;

    JSchemaGenerator generator = new();
    JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Foo)); // generate schema from object
```

```json
    {
        ...,
        "Bar": { // <- this should not be shown in the Json schema
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just mark them with [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) and eliminate `ShouldSerializeBar()`?  Json.NET Schema only has access to type metadata so has no way of knowing that `ShouldSerializeBar()` always returns false (and it might not, in a derived class).

Comment: I've tried it with `JsonIgnore`. But the properties were still contained in the output JSON and JSON schema. With `ShoudSerializeBar` I could suppress the output in the JSON but it's still in the schema.

Comment: That's surprising, let me confirm.  But in the meantime, you might check to make sure you are using [`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) and not [`System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=net-6.0).  Only the former applies to Newtonsoft.

Comment: Indeed there was System.Test.Json used in the model. If I change it to Newtonsoft.Json it's the same behaviour in the generated schema.

Comment: `[JsonIgnore]` works for me.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GYnmYS which shows that `ShouldSerializeBar()` works to suppress serialization but not schema generation and https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ofc6lu which shows that `[JsonIgnore]` does both.  So, does *Use `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]`* answer your question?

Comment: Interesting. :-\ I'll take a look tomorrow where the error is in my code. Already thanks for the hints.

Comment: A [mcve] is needed here.  You might be using System.Text.Json for serialization without realizing it, in which case using Json.NET Schema for schema generation is likely to introduce inconsistencies.  See e.g. [JsonIgnore attribute keeps serializing properties in ASP.NET Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58499339/3744182).